# ImportError: No module named SpeechRecognition

Tags: python, pip, speech-recognition

My code is

```
import SpeechRecognition as sr

# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

# recognize speech using Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition
BING_KEY = "Somevalue"  # Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition API keys 32-character lowercase hexadecimal strings
try:
    print("Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition thinks you said " + r.recognize_bing(audio, key=BING_KEY))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Microsoft Bing Voice Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

When I run it, I got

```
ImportError: No module named SpeechRecognition
```

I think I did install this module:

```
>pip list
SpeechRecognition (3.6.5)
```

the code given by the git repository is like this

```
import speech_recognition as sr
```

but it isn't working either

Comment: Sure you're using the same environment to install the package and run your script? Did you maybe use pip to install and python3 to run it or pip3 to install and python (symlinked to python2) to run?

Comment: @Daniel I installed with pip and ran as Python

Comment: I just tried (installation and import) and, indeed, the correct package name is `speech_recognition`. I would bet on what @Daniel said.

Comment: Trivial checks and further information: `python --version`, `pip --version`, `pip install SpeechRecognition`, `python -m speech_recognition`. Run all of them in the same console and comment on their outputs.

Comment: >python --version
Python 2.7.10
>pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
>pip install SpeechRecognition
Requirement already satisfied: SpeechRecognition in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>python -m speech_recognition
/usr/bin/python: No module named speech_recognition

Comment: BTW, I installed python with Brew(on Macbook)

Comment: Okay, last guess since you installed everything via brew. Maybe you're using osx default python2 and brew's pip. Can you please run the following commands: `which python`, `which pip`. And also try to launch speech_recogntion with `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/python -m speech_recognition`?

Comment: I don't have my macbook handy right now, not sure if the binaries is located here: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/python`, `/usr/local/bin/python2.7/python`, .. :)

Answer (score 8):

I think the problem is

```
import SpeechRecognition as sr
```

where you should use

```
import speech_recognition as sr
```