# No module named 'speechrecognition' python3.8.5

Tags: python, python-3.8

**HERE IS MY CODE:**

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr .Microphone() as source:
     print('Say Something')
audio = r.listen(source)
voice_data = recognize_google(audio)
print(voice_data)
```

My problem is when I run the code it shows, `No module named 'speech_recognition'` although I have already used `pip` to install it using visual code as the IDE I've used.

Comment: Did you look at code examples on https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/2.1.3/ ? It's `import speech_recognition as sr`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named SpeechRecognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806542/importerror-no-module-named-speechrecognition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a typo

it's `speech_recognition` not `speechrecognition`

it may be installed via pip as

`pip install SpeechRecognition`

or

`pip3 install SpeechRecognition`

Comment: I've tried said "speech_recognition" yet it still said ModuleNotFoundError:

Comment: note: on my system (windows) the name was `speech_recognition`